# MVC: Delete and Insert logic should be on Model or Service layer?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller

My code is NodeJS but this question should not be language specific. I'm implementing a logic to interact with a database table and I'm having some doubts regarding the logic to insert, read and delete (I don't need update), should be in a service or in the model.
The read I guess it's a good practice to have it in the model (as a getter), but for insert and delete seem to me that should be in a service.

Am I wrong?